# What is the maximum text length in tokens that can be given as input for summarisation task using a sentence transformer models

Tags: huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, summarization, sentence-transformers

Most Bert models take a maximum input length of 512 tokens. When I used sentence transformer multi-qa-distilbert-cos-v1 model with bert-extractive-summarizer for summarisation task. A text with 792 tokens was accepted by the model and the summary contained the last line from the original text. Usually the text after 512 tokens is truncated by the model and not considered for nlp task. The documentation also states the max sequence length of 512 tokens. How is the model able to read beyond 512 tokens?

Comment: Is it possible to share code in colab notebook? maybe I can play around a bit to see why it the case?